# How use qml types in main qml file from other qml file

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, signals-slots

I have a `TextField` in **main.qml** file

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

 header: ToolBar{
    id: tbMain

    TextField{
        id: tfsearch
    }
}
}
```

in **main.qml** file I have `StackView` that I add searchresult.qml to this stackview.

I want to know in searchresult.qml how use textchanged signal and text property of TextField that is in main.qml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a signal from one qml to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407583/how-to-send-a-signal-from-one-qml-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `searchresult.qml`:

```
Connections {
  target: tfsearch
  onTextChanged: doStuff()
}
```

Comment: tfsearch is in main.qml how can i use that

Comment: @mohsen - `id`s are accessible as long as they are "visible", which means that they are down the object tree and not shadowed by another id or property name. They are not visible if they exist in another tree branch or detached from the tree altogether.

Comment: Hm. It is not good style to use cross referenences through different QML files. So either you use the `onTextChanged()` signal to access the element in `Stackview` using `currentItem` property or you save the id of `tfsearch` to the `StackView` component and access it with attached `Stack.view.tfsearch` property in `searchresult.qml`.

Comment: @sk2212 nonsense. It is a core language feature and is 100% OK if used properly. Yes it can also be misused, but that applies to everything. There is no "cross reference" taking place, there is a plain reference to a context property.  Furthermore, the first half of your recommendation doesn't work if the particular item is not current, the second one is completely unnecessary `id`s are automatically converted to the equivalent of a property for the source root element, remapping to the actual object instance.

Comment: Sorry but referencing directly to an id in ANOTHER QML file is really bad design. Using this approach will couple these components. They will not working as standalone components. Please read some good documentation until you say "nonsense".

Comment: Nope, the very fact that ids are exported as component scope properties clearly indicates the intent to use them in tandem with dynamic scoping. It would have been easier to constrain ids to a single source, yet the developers of qml deliberately took it further, with the intent of that feature to be used where applicable. The documentation is for nebws, I highly doubt there is a person on this planet that has pushed qml further than I have, having discovered numerous bugs and limitations in the process. Sorry but if anyone doesn't know what he's talking about that is definitely you.

Comment: @dtech tanks if you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891976/qml-types-in-main-qml-file-is-not-accessable-in-all-other-page