# Send a signal between two object instances in different QML files

Tags: qt, qml, signals-slots

I'm trying to send a signal from an object in one QML file to another object in a different QML file, but can't seem to find any good resources to use as a guide. Most of the examples I have come across show signals and slots being used to communicate between either two objects implemented in the same QML file (i.e. inside the same component), or in two different component files that come together inside a third QML file, which differs from my use case.

I need to send a `string` value from an object in a QML file (which represents a screen) to another object in a different QML file (representing yet another screen). The way the screens are linked currently is via `StackView` QML type in the `main.qml` file.

The closest I have seen the same problem described is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407583/how-to-send-a-signal-from-one-qml-to-another). The problem with the accepted answer in my case is the fact that the objects `Rect1` and `Rect2` are later defined in the same file. This means that they can be given an `id` and the signal and slot can be connected together, something I'm unable to do on my side.

Here's some code to demonstrate the problem.

`main.qml`:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: app_container
    width: 480
    height: 600
    visible: true

    StackView {
        id: screen_stack
        anchors.fill: parent
  
        initialItem: Screen1 {
        }
    }
}
```

`Screen1`:

```
Item {
    id: screen_1
    width: 480
    height: 600

    property var input

    TextField {
        id: user_input
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - 100
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        placeholderText: qsTr("Enter your name")

        onEditingFinsihed: {
            input = user_input.text
        }
    }

    Button {
        width: parent.width
        height: 100
        anchors.top: user_input.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        onClicked: {
            console.log("Moving to Screen2")
            screen_stack.push("qrc:/Screen2.qml")
        } 
    }
}
```

`Screen2`:

```
Item {
    id: screen_2
    width: 480
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "yellow"

        Text {
            id: txt_rect
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            text: qsTr("")
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is send the user input from TextField `user_input` in `Screen1` to Text `txt_rect` in `Screen2`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push properties:

```
screen_stack.push("qrc:/Screen2.qml", {"inputText": user_input.text})
```

Screen2:

```
Item {
id: screen_2
width: 480
height: 600

property var inputText

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "yellow"

    Text {
        id: txt_rect
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        text: screen_2.inputText
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Will try this out. Does this approach require that if the information being sent from Screen1 is needed on Screen3, I would have to send it first to Screen2? In other words, does `inputText` need be on the same screen as the one we are going to?

Comment: Yes, you can only set a property in the next screen you push to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does work well enough for me to get the job done but I was wondering how the same functionality can somehow be implemented using signals and slots.

Comment: Why? Signals and slots are not the solution to everything

Comment: @MohammadAli Please mark my answer as correct to help others. (What benefits would signals have here? I do not see any.)

Comment: @GrecKo: Mostly because I need to push the information to a screen that's not adjacent to the one receiving the data, which means I'm having to propagate the data through screens that don't require it. I would like to avoid that however way I can, signals or no signals.

Comment: You could also create a property at the StackView, which every Screen can read or write.